# DNS forwarder response being ignored

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

We run bind on our internal DNS servers.

We have a high-availability subnet group sitting in AWS that provides RDS.
In order to manage access over internal links we want the RDS instance to resolve to its' private IP - not the public IP.

As the IP changes from time to time I have set up a forward in our dns that will resolve the RDS against the Amazon DNS server and give us the current private IP:

```
zone "coivvuccn9hs.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com" IN {
   type forward;
   forward only;
   forwarders { 
       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; 
   };
};
```

When I do a query from one of the internal DNS servers against the AWS DNS:
dig @xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx server.coivvuccn9hs.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com
I get the right answer

However when I do a 
dig @localhost server.coivvuccn9hs.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com
I get the public IP, even though a tcpdump shows that the server does query the AWS DNS server and gets a valid response.

My understanding is that a forwarder will get precedence over a response from the root servers, so why do I get the public IP back, and not the private IP?

This is the answer I get:

```
dig @localhost server.coivvuccn9hs.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.23.rc1.el6_5.1 <<>> @localhost server.coivvuccn9hs.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 5580
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 13, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;server.coivvuccn9hs.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
server.coivvuccn9hs.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com. 5  IN CNAME <somename>.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.
<somename>.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com. 604800  IN A <public ip>

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com. 900 IN NS  u6.amazonaws.com.
eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com. 900 IN NS  pdns1.ultradns.net.
eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com. 900 IN NS  u2.amazonaws.com.
eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com. 900 IN NS  ns1.p31.dynect.net.
eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com. 900 IN NS  u4.amazonaws.com.
eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com. 900 IN NS  pdns3.ultradns.org.
eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com. 900 IN NS  ns4.p31.dynect.net.
eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com. 900 IN NS  u3.amazonaws.com.
eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com. 900 IN NS  pdns5.ultradns.info.
eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com. 900 IN NS  u1.amazonaws.com.
eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com. 900 IN NS  ns2.p31.dynect.net.
eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com. 900 IN NS  ns3.p31.dynect.net.
eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com. 900 IN NS  u5.amazonaws.com.

;; Query time: 489 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Aug 24 15:13:53 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 416
```

Comment: For clarity, can you confirm that *tcpdump shows that the server does query the AWS DNS server and gets a valid response* was a response that had the private IP?

Comment: That is correct - I can see the private IP in the answer in A:
`09:47:32.007021 IP 172.28.200.11.31772 > 172.29.0.2.domain: 11853+ [1au] A? gamingstats.coivvuccn9hs.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com. (81)
09:47:32.256192 IP 172.29.0.2.domain > 172.28.200.11.31772: 11853 2/0/1 CNAME ec2-52-30-30-69.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com., A 172.29.7.136 (145)`

Answer (score 1):

Notice the dig/nslookup response was a `CNAME` pointing to `<somename>.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com` (`<somename>` being omitted on your post).

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
server.coivvuccn9hs.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com. 5  IN CNAME <somename>.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.
```

This means that the lookup for `server.coivvuccn9hs.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com` is actually pointing to the `<somename>.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com` hostname.

Since your bind server only has a forwarding rule in place for the `rds.amazonaws.com` it now does a default forward lookup for the `compute.amazonaws.com` lookup, thus resulting in a public ip.

Therefore the solution is to add a second forward zone for the "real" address after the CNAME resolution. You should then get the private IP returned in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Smells like a DNSSEC validation issue to me. Do you have `dnssec-validation yes;` in the main/view `options` section? If so, try adding `dnssec-must-be-secure domain.tld no;` immediately after it.

HTH-RB

Comment: Thanks - I tried that but it didn't resolve the issue. I enabled some debugging on the query function and saw this:`Sep 7 16:26:22  named  34692  resolver: debug 1: fetch: ec2-52-30-30-69.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/A
Sep 7 16:26:21  named  34692  resolver: debug 1: fetch: gamingstats.coivvuccn9hs.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com/A `. As you can see from the packet dump above the reply contains a cname and an A record. It seems like it ignores the a record and goes and looks up the cname instead, which points it back to the public IP.

Comment: That's unfortunate... but it _has_ to be an additional query, after the initial forwarder response, which is sent to the root servers (most probably), overriding the cache. The resolver cache always takes precedence over a new (forward) query. A broader and more detailed analysis of a traffic capture will be needed...